# php mysql database date range form

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, range

I Need fot visitor change data range , i Try to mysql code put variable data range set 'start' and 'end' but not work, further must in format like this : '2016-10-24 08:00:00' 2016-10-20 08:00:00' 
on phpmyadmin

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $("#date_range").submit(function(){
          $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:".weekly_concession.php?" + new Date().getTime(),
            dataType:"text",
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend:function(){
              $("#loading").show();
            },
            success:function(response){
                $("#report_result").append(response);
                $("#loading").hide();
            } 
          })
          return false;
        });
    });
    </script>


<div align="center">
<form name="date_range" id="date_range" method="post" style="width: 454px" >
<fieldset>
<legend>Start Date : </legend>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" name="start" id="datepicker"/>
<legend>End Date : </legend>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" name="end" id="datepicker2"/>
<button class="btn btn-inverse" type="submit" name="click" >
<i class="icon icon-print icon-white"></i> 
Run Report</button>
</fieldset>
</form></div>
<br><br>


$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(489153X91X359) AS jidlo_1_BAD FROM lime_survey_489153
WHERE 489153X91X359 LIKE '%BAD%' AND startdate BETWEEN '$datepicker' AND '$datepicker2' ");
```

OR

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(489153X91X359) AS jidlo_1_OK FROM lime_survey_489153
WHERE 489153X91X359 LIKE '%OK%' AND startdate BETWEEN 'start' AND 'end' ");

$values7 = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $values7 .= $row['jidlo_1_OK'];
}
```

Comment: I am unable to understand what you want ? Do you want to filter record `between` date range ?

Comment: `199184X87X343` is a distressing name for a column

Comment: Now, when I want to that this script work, I need to write it in this form: '2016-09-02 08:00:00'
But I would like to that visitors could only choose date, not to write it in any form.

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains this

```
        startdate > '2016-10-20 08:00:00' AND '2016-09-02 08:00:00'
```

But, I think you want it to be

```
       startdate >=  '2016-09-02 08:00:00'
   and startdate <   '2016-10-20 08:00:00'
```

or maybe

```
       startdate  BETWEEN '2016-09-02 08:00:00' AND '2016-10-20 08:00:00'
```

Notice that `BETWEEN` takes the form  `value BETWEEN low AND high`.

If you're asking about visitor-preferred time zones, that's not even a little bit clear from your question.

Comment: I Try but not working: (sorry CTRL+K not working )                                                                               SELECT `489153X91X359` AS hodnota, COUNT(`id`) AS soucet FROM `lime_survey_489153` 
WHERE startdate >='2016-08-16 08:00:00'
AND startdatete <= '2016-10-20 08:00:00'
AND startdatete `489153X91X359` != ''
GROUP BY `489153X91X359`